# Why can't my function return a true value?

Tags: vb.net

I get an error saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Additional information: Conversion from string "Admin" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

When I run the program putting in the correct values for username and password I don't get the error, when I put in the wrong values the `If` statement proceeds correctly.
I'm remade the program countless time and still get this error. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Login
Dim Password As String
Dim Username As String

Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    //TODO: This line of code loads data into the "DatabaseADataSet.Logon" table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.LogonTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseADataSet.Logon)

End Sub

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Username = txtUsername.Text
    Password = txtPassword.Text
    CheckUser(Username, Password)
End Sub


Function CheckUser(Username As String, Password As String) As String

    If Me.LogonTableAdapter.ScalarQuery(Username, Password) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Succesful")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login unsuccesful, would you like to register", "Unsuccesful login.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If DialogResult.Yes Then
            frmRegister.Show()
        End If
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What does `ScalarQuery` return? Consider to switch to `OPTION STRICT ON`. Then you learn how to prevent such runtime exceptions in future.

Comment: This is the function ScalarQuery

    SELECT        Username, [Password]
    FROM            Logon
    WHERE        (Username = ?) AND ([Password] = ?)

Comment: Your SQL returns both a user name and password. You need to research what SCALAR means. Either way, it does NOT return a Boolean type, it is returning the user name which it then tries to convert to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful, as Tim mentioned (+1 for Option Strict), to know what ScalarQuery does.

Going under the assumption that your ScalarQuery performs an `ExecuteScalar` on a SQL query, it will return the first column of your query.  In this case, it looks like you passed in 'Admin' and it's corresponding password.  Since your supplied query is selecting the Username column as the first ordinal, that's what your ScalarQuery is returning.  Since "Admin" (string) cannot cast to `True` (boolean) - you get the error you posted.

Given what you've posted, you'd want to either structure your SQL query to return a boolean value which can cast, or change your IF conditional to apply the correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

What does ScalarQuery return? A string for true/false?

If so, then compare with "true" or "false":

```
If Me.LogonTableAdapter.ScalarQuery(Username, Password) = "True" Then
```

As others have stated, you should probably turn on OPTION STRICT

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It returns the first column of the first row in the result set or Null Reference. The latter can be converted to False but the content of the given cell can't be converted to True.

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed the problem for anyone looking in the future. I changed the if statement to see if the value is nothing or not.

```
If Me.LogonTableAdapter.ScalarQuery(Username, Password) IsNot Nothing Then
```